# Why is my Angular JS ng-show empty list div shows up for a split second while API is being called?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-show="!activities.length">No items in feed</div>
```

I use the above code to show a message when a user has no items in their feed. On that same page I have a radio button to show different types of feeds (e.g. just yours, or all your friends, etc.). When the user selects a different option, it makes a post back to my API which takes a second, but while the api is grabbing the data the empty list message displays for a second.

Is there an easy way to resolve this?

Comment: `ngClock` will take care about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ngCloack` directive for this:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to use ng-bind as many people recommend it over ng-cloak:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind

I personally have had issues where even using ng-cloak there is a slight markup flash.